# How to use Adblock AND a VPN

Tags: privacy, vpn, proxy, adblock-plus

I'm using Private Internet Access's VPN via its [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privateinternetaccess.android) and now I'd also like to additionally use [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install).
The problem however is that I apparently can only use either VPN or Adblock Plus - but not both in combination.
Is it possible to use both by changing some setting in either of the Apps or of my phone ?

It says it couldn't change the proxy settings of my phone so I should do it manually. But as all traffic is routed through the VPN changing the proxy-name to "localhost" and the proxy-port to "2020" didn't help. It keeps on waiting for traffic on Port 2020. I guess it comes down to routing the VPN traffic through the proxy. But maybe there's also another solution to it (like another Adblock App that works differently for example).

---

**My phone**:
Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, I8160
Firmware 4.1.2
Rooted

**The Error Message** (roughly translated):
"Seemingly no traffic was routed through adblock plus. Adblock Plus couldn't change the proxy settings of your device. Please configure them manually."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good reasons why you cannot use such a combination:

- routing your VPN traffic via another proxy might compromise it, thus rendering your VPN useless
- doing it the other way around won't work, as the Adblock proxy then would need to be *behind* the VPN one – which *you* cannot establish *on your device*

So what you need is, as you correctly pointed out, an ad-blocker working by different means. Examples include (without giving any recommendation here, just listing possibilities):

- something working via the `hosts` file (i.e. routing all ad-requests "to `/dev/null`" (or rather to `127.0.0.1`, which is your device itself, which doesn't have them → nothing returned to display)
- something "nulling" the ad modules themselves (i.e. "disabling" them)

None of those are "to be found" at *Google Play* for obvious reasons (though there might be some which *Google* either didn't recognize yet, or which have the corresponding activity hidden from the UI itself by hiding it, or which are simply ignored as "not fit for international use").

I could name some of the latter two categories, e.g. *LBE Security Master* (which is only available in a Chinese version on *Play* (see [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=46695347&postcount=2010) for a localized English version)). There are also several apps working with the `hosts` solution, which you can find on e.g. *F-Droid* or *Aptoide* (see my app-list on [Ad-Blockers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker) for examples).

Comment: Thanks! I actually was pretty surprised Adblock Plus required proxy-settings as I thought it would work by hosts-file settings and other local set ups only. I'm using **AdAway** now.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Yes, that's an app I can approve (though I never used it myself; I use one of those evil "module disablers" ;) But I also usually purchase apps, if possible – so the "evil ones" are just applied to the "freemium apps" not having a "payed companion", basically.

Answer (score 0):

For non-rooted phones see my relevant question [*here*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169440/how-to-run-a-firewall-and-an-adblocker-on-a-non-rooted-phone-at-the-same-time/169441#169441). Currently I'm using a VPN connection for my NetGuard firewall.

If you have a non-rooted phone you can use a VPN and then use the browser [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) and install an adblock AddOn to it (like [UBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/ublock-mobile/)). Or simply use the [Firefox Klar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.klar) browser which blocks ads and tracking by default.

As far as I know there are no adblockers for non-rooted phones that also block ads in apps and don't use VPN. One exception I know of is pi-hole which isn't a solution in my and most cases.