# How to run a firewall and an AdBlocker on a non-rooted phone at the same time?

Tags: rooting, privacy, vpn, firewall, adblock-plus

I have a non-rooted Android phone and would like to use both a Firewall and an Adblocker at the same time. How can I do this?

I could only find Firewalls and Adblockers for non-rooted phones that use use VPN with only *one* VPN connection being allowed.

Comment: You can use [adguard](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.adguard.android) for this purpose which has the capability of both a firewall and an adblocker. It sets up a local vpn for non rooted phones. It also has a proxy mode. ( maybe inorder to use with other vpns)

Comment: @NikhilAlexGeorge Why not make that an answer? Perfectly fits the issue. From the app description: *It not only removes ads from browsers and applications on your smartphone/tablet, but also features such tools as firewall and phishing protection.* Sounds like exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [adguard](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.adguard.android) for this purpose which has the capability of both a firewall and an adblocker. It sets up a local vpn for non rooted phones. It also has a proxy mode. ( inorder to use with other vpns).

Comment: This sounds great. I knew about it but didn't know that it's also a firewall. Going to check it out. So theoretically I could use it as my firewall and my AdBlocker AND use a VPN? I guess the only issue would be that it's not free but maybe it's worth it.

Comment: Yes you can use it along with another VPN by changing the mode to HTTP Proxy mode. It creates a local http proxy server to filter traffic then. But in this case it requires root access. If not , you have to configure the proxy manually in the wifi proxy settings.

Comment: Yes, it is paid- suggest first take an yearly licence and wait for Easter / Black Friday / other sales - I got lifetime licence for the cost of about two year licence

Answer (score 0):

You can install a firewall for non-rooted phones that uses VPN like the open source *[NetGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard)* and then use the browser [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en) and install [an Adblock AddOn](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/search/?q=adblock&appver=&platform=) to it (like uBlock Origin) or simply use the [Firefox Klar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.klar) browser.

Sadly I couldn't figure out a way to also use an additional non-root Adblocker that also blocks ads in apps but maybe there are some other alternatives. Pi-hole isn't really a solution in my and most cases.